# Global object / scope and undefined circular references

Tags: javascript, node.js, global, circular-reference

I'm not sure I understand the results of these few experiences :

Experience n°1 (in new command line) :

```
> _
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
> global
{ global: [Circular],
  ...
 _: [Circular], }
> _
{ global: [Circular],
  ...
 _: [Circular], }
```

Experience n°2 (in new command line) :

```
> _
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
> var http = require('http');
undefined
> _
undefined
> global._
undefined
> global
{ global: [Circular],
  ...
 _: [Circular], }
```

Experience n°3 (in new command line) :

```
> _
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
> Object.prototype.toString.call(global._)
'[object Undefined]'
> _
'[object Undefined]'
```

So this is what I understood until now :

1. From experience n°1 :

   - The `global` object is build when the first `get global` is triggered.
   - The `_` circular reference is then added too (which seems logical).
2. From experience n°2 :

   - After accessing a property of the `global` object (`require()` in this case), the `_` is set.
   - For some reason it is set but is `undefined` not a circular reference.
3. From experience n°3 :

   - When accessing `_` through it's property in the `global` object (`global._`) and using it as an argument of a method or a statement, the result of said operation reassigns the value of `_` to that result.

So here are my questions :

- Why aren't circular references accessible immediately compared to other properties of global like `require` ?
- Why are results of methods / statements that use `global._` reassigning `_` ?
- After accessing other global properties like `require`, why is `_`'s value set to `undefined` rather than a `[Circular]` ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are results of methods / statements that use `global._` reassigning `_` ?

`_` holds the value of the last evaluated statement:

```
> 'foo'
'foo'
> _
'foo'

> var http = require('http');
undefined
> _
undefined
```

Thus, it's not the use of `_` that changes `_`, it's *doing anything* that changes `_`. It is initially undeclared because there is no previous statement.

> After accessing other global properties like require, why is `_`'s value set to undefined rather than a `[Circular]` ?

The only reason you see `[Circular]` in your first example is because `_` has just been set equal to `global` (because `global` is the last evaluated statement), so `global._` circularly refers back to `global`. In the case of your assignment statement with `require`, the line yields `undefined`, so that's the value that gets placed in `_`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! I never new / thought that ```_``` would behave that way ! That behaviour is magical ! ^^